# Regular expression for validating football score

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression for the score format:

```
0-2 -> True
a-b -> False
1-a -> False
00-01 -> False
00-0000 -> False
```

I've tried: ^(\d+)-(\d+)*, it works for most cases, but I can't pass the last two cases (00-01, 00-0000, ...)

Comment: For regex, please include in the tags the programming language you're using.

Comment: `(\d+)-(\d+)` works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is either zero or a series of digits that doesn't start with zero:

```
\b(0|[1-9]\d*)-(0|[1-9]\d*)\b
```

(`\b` indicates string boundary)